# Approximate solution of 2nd order DE near an irregular singular point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, approximation

I have the following DE:
$$
f'' + p(t)f' + q(t) f = 0
$$

where
$$
p(t)= \frac{a}{t} \text{ and } q(t) = b\left(-\frac{1}{t^2} + \frac{\epsilon}{t^3} \right)
$$
with $a,b, \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0<\epsilon \ll 1$. Now, if $\epsilon = 0$, the above equation is just a Cauchy-Euler equation that I have solved exactly. However, for $\epsilon \neq 0$ we see that $t=0$ is an irregular singular point and as such I am interested in an asymptotic approximation of the solution in the region $t \in (0, 1)$.

I am not very familiar with asymptotic analysis, but I *think* I might be able to use the method of dominant balance to write down the asymptotic behavior as $t \rightarrow 0^+$. However, I am curious if there is some better way to do this given that I have the solution for the $\epsilon = 0$ case. Is there a way to get an approximate solution in powers of $\epsilon$, for example?

Any pointers or resources would be greatly appreciated - just something to get me headed down the right path.

EDIT:
Robert Israel has pointed out below that an exact solution exists for this differential equation. Nonetheless, I am still interested in the approximate solution. The more general question involves equations with 
$$
q(t) = b \left( -\frac{1}{t^2} + \frac{\epsilon_1}{t^3} + \frac{\epsilon_2}{t^4} \right)
$$
Or even higher orders of $t^{-n}$, and where $\epsilon_i$ are small parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your differential equation has closed-form solutions

$$ \eqalign{f \left( t \right) &=c_{{1}}{t}^{1/2-a/2}{{ J}_{-\sqrt {{a}^{2}-2\,a
+4\,b+1}}\left(2\,{\frac {\sqrt {b\epsilon}}{\sqrt {t}}}\right)}\cr &+c_{{2
}}{t}^{1/2-a/2}{{ Y}_{-\sqrt {{a}^{2}-2\,a+4\,b+1}}\left(2\,{\frac 
{\sqrt {b\epsilon}}{\sqrt {t}}}\right)}}
$$

where $J$ and $Y$ are Bessel functions.  The asymptotics of these functions
as $t \to 0$ are known.

EDIT: The transformation $f(t) = t^{1/2 - a/2} g(2 \sqrt{b \epsilon/t})$ makes
the equation into
$$ s^2 g''(s) + s g'(s) + (s^2 + 2a - a^2 - 4 b - 1) g(s) = 0$$

Your second differential equation has closed-form solutions as well:

$$\eqalign{f \left( t \right) &=c_{{1}}{t}^{-a/2+1}{{ M}_{{\frac {-i\sqrt {b}
\epsilon_{{1}}}{2\sqrt {\epsilon_{{2}}}}},\,\sqrt {{a}^{2}-2\,a+4
\,b+1}/2}\left({\frac {2\,i\sqrt {\epsilon_{{2}}}\sqrt {b}}{t}}\right)}\cr &+
c_{{2}}{t}^{-a/2+1}{{ W}_{{\frac {-i\sqrt {b}\epsilon_{{1}}}{2
\sqrt {\epsilon_{{2}}}}},\,\sqrt {{a}^{2}-2\,a+4\,b+1}/2}\left({
\frac {2\,i\sqrt {\epsilon_{{2}}}\sqrt {b}}{t}}\right)}}
$$
where $M$ and $W$ are Whittaker functions.

Comment: This is helpful. Do you have a resource that shows this derivation? I am also still interested in the above question since a) I only need an approximate solution, so if there is an approximate form that is ‘nicer’ that would be good and b) the more general problem I am working on involves $q(x)$ containing even higher terms of $1/x^n$.

Comment: I used Maple to solve the differential equation.  The point is that a certain transformation (which in hindsight you can get from the above solution) gives you a Bessel equation.

Comment: Thank you. I will think more deeply about what transformations I should make. In the meantime I will accept your answer - thanks.

Comment: I am admittedly still having a difficult time identifying what transformation should be made. If at all possible, could you make that a bit more explicit? No need for great detail but I am stumped here.